# jquery file upload using formData not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I am trying a simple file upload of a tar file using jquery. But I get an Invalid archive format from my server. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I cannot change the server code. It comes from another team.

Edit 1: Response from chrome:
[image]
My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testFileUpload">
  <input type="file" name="selectedFile"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();

        var form = $('#testFileUpload')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      url: g_url_version+'/hosting/apps',
      data: data,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      timeout: 600000,
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Token-Id', getCookieToken());
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Connector-Id', 'TestSeed');
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
      },
      error: function (e) {
        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

[image]

I can upload the file using postman via Binary as shown below but not via formData.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You are `event.preventDefault()` in the `$("#btnSubmit").click`. You need to do that in `$('#testFileUpload').submit`. The form is still submitting.

Comment: I just changed the id before putting it on stackoverflow. that was not the issue.

Comment: That is the button. You want the form.

Comment: oops will change that.

Answer (score 4):

Bind the submit event handler rather than click on the button as you need to prevent the 
default form submission and send manual ajax call

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
```

to

```
  $("#testFileUpload").on('submit', function(event) {
```

and simply use `this` to get the form object inside it

```
 var form = this;
```

copy the code below it should upload the file correctly if you have a simple `php` file with

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

it should show the below in the console

```
SUCCESS :  Array
(
    [userid] => oemr@omer.com
    [filelabel] => 
)
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => IMG_20160521_092941676.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => F:\xampp\tmp\phpD881.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 4867779
        )

)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testFileUpload").on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var form = this;
    var data = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      url: g_url_version + '/hosting/apps',
      data: data,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      timeout: 600000,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Token-Id', getCookieToken());
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Connector-Id', 'TestSeed');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testFileUpload">
  <input type="file" name="selectedFile" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: still getting  500


------WebKitFormBoundarySlHFXS7GQ4gKUuS4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selectedFile"; filename="xxx.tar"
Content-Type: application/x-tar


------WebKitFormBoundarySlHFXS7GQ4gKUuS4--

Comment: `500` is `internal server error`, on your server side code, can you comment out the request headers in `beforeRequest()` as i commented it out while testing because the `getCookieToken()` function wasnt added. @user1556718 otherwise the problem is on the server side

Comment: I cannot change the server side code. the same api works when using postman with binary option to upload file

Comment: that is strange, it straight and simple code if used with a noarmal php file, as mentioned in the answer, can you comment out the `enctype` in your ajax request and then check once? @user1556718

Comment: Same with postman. when i send the file as binary it works, but when i send it as formData it fails

Comment: for sure, it has nothing to do with the javascript part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in following way:
Update your click handler to; 
**jQUERY:**

```
event.preventDefault();
var data = new FormData();
data.append("file",$('input[name="selectedFile"]').files[0]);
// your ajax call looks fine. Use the same.
```

Comment: Din't work. I changed it to below but it still dint work data.append("selectedFile",$('input[name="selectedFile"]').get(0).files[0]);

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#contactform").validate({
    errorClass: "errors_lable",
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "Please enter email address.",
            email: "Please enter Valid email address.",
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        try {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("LogoName", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
            formData.append("email", isCollege);
            waitingDialog.show('Please Wait While Processing...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: "https://code0.ww.com/index.php/...../RegisterSchool",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    waitingDialog.hide('Please Wait While Processing...');
                    if (data.ResponseHeader.response_type == 'success') {
                        //                          $('#msg').show();
                        //                          $('#msg').html("<span style='color:#b9efb9'><b>Thankyou For Register</b></span>");
                        alert('Thankyou For Register');
                    } else if (data.ResponseHeader.response_type == 'error') {
                        //$('#msg').show();
                        //$('#msg').html("<span style='color:red'><b>Opps! There is some  error, Please Try again latter.</b></span>");
                        alert('Somithing Went Wrong Please Try Again Latter');
                    }
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('Somithing Went Wrong Please Try Again Latter');
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's a bit pointless to answer a 1 year old question since he probably have solved it already. beside your code example is far of from the OP's structure in terms of markup and javascript. you don't explain anything either. from the look of the postman image i would say that the correct answer would be not to send a formData but just send the binary (file) instead of a FormData

Comment: Right but when I searched the answer i found solution  after 2 hours. so my answer is for that who stuck in such problem. And when you send the data by appending it in formData the images file show as binary.