# Ajax submit an image with form - pass the FormData - trigger submit

Tags: ajax, forms, image

I simply want to use ajax to submit a form with an image from a phone.

If I use the below code as a simple function - the form data is not passed.
If I use the code as is - it works but the user has to click the submit button.

**How do I either pass the FormData properly to a simple $.ajax({}); submit?**

OR

**How do I trigger the code below when a picture is taken or selected?**

I have this - it works fine when user clicks submit:

```
// how do I trigger this when image file is selected?
$("#Upload_Form").submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        // OR - how do I get FormData with image without using: '$("#Upload_Form").submit(function(e)'
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
           // POST details are here etc.
        });
    });
```

Comment: so you basically want the form to be submitted automatically when you select a file for upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the change event for the `file` input like below and then trigger the `submit` event of the form or make an `ajax` call right away with the `FormData` see below demo.

If you want to know how to submit image using `FormData` and `ajax` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937704/jquery-file-upload-using-formdata-not-working/50937957#50937957)

```js
$("#my-form").on('submit', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  // OR - how do I get FormData with image without using: '$("#Upload_Form").submit(function(e)'
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  console.log("sending Ajax call now");
  $.ajax({
    // POST details are here etc.
  });
});


$("#my-file").on('change', function() {
  //you can either trigger the form submit here
  var form = $("#my-form");
  $("#my-form").submit();

  //OR
  //use this to send the ajax call to upload the image
  // var form=$("#my-form")[0];
  // var formData = new FormData(form);

  // $.ajax({
  //     type: "POST",
  //     url: 'your/url',
  //     data: formData,
  //     processData: false,
  //     contentType: false,
  //     success: function (data) {
  //         console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
  //     },
  //     error: function (e) {
  //         console.log("ERROR : ", e);
  //     }
  // });


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="my-file" id="my-file" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

## `Update`

Note: if you want to use an ajax call to send the formData you need to set the  `processData` and `contentType` to `false`. `contentType: false` only available from jQuery 1.6 onwards.

Comment: I did try 'document.getElementById("GROOMING_Upload_Form").submit();' is that not the same thing as your var form=$("#my-form");  form.submit(); ? It did not pass the form as data.

As well - are '$("#my-form").on('submit', function(e)' and '$("#Upload_Form").submit(function(e)' not the same?

Comment: if you used the above parameters that I added in the answer there is a mistake in the data parameter `data: data,` should be `data: formData,` i just updated the code. @Stnfordly

Comment: yes both are valid,but there is a mistake when using jquery we need to specify `$("#my-form")[0]`, which i was missing, you just need to trigger the submit, and `$("#my-form").on('submit', function(e)` and `$("#Upload_Form").submit(function(e)` are same, given that the selector you are using is the form's `id`, other than that the `.submit(function(e){})` is just a shorthand for the `.on('submit',function(){})` and what do you mean by it did not pass the formdata @Stnfordly , kindly add your complete code how are you sending the ajax call

Comment: All I mean is - when I try calling 'document.getElementById("GROOMING_Upload_Form").submit()' - for some reason 'FormData(this)' does not seem to grab the form values and image file.

There is no additional code - 'document.getElementById("GROOMING_Upload_Form").submit()' - just something I tried. I will try your answer as soon as I can. Thanks